# Why am I getting No result defined for action in Struts 2 application

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2

Currently i am new to struts 2 but i have the knowledge but when i am trying to perform validation in struts to i am getting problem in my struts 2 example which is a  custom validation example. all code is below:

index.jsp

```
  <%-- 
    Document   : index
    Created on : Jan 9, 2014, 10:58:52 AM
    Author     : manoj.sharma
--%>

<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<s:form action="register">  
    <s:textfield name="name" label="Name"></s:textfield>  
    <s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>  
    <s:submit value="register"></s:submit>  
</s:form>
```

welcome.jsp

```
    <%-- 
    Document   : welcome
    Created on : Jan 9, 2014, 11:08:37 AM
    Author     : manoj.sharma
--%>

<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
Name:<s:property value="name"/><br/>  
Password:<s:property value="password"/><br/>
```

RegisterAction.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.org.my.action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
/**
 *
 * @author manoj.sharma
 */
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport{  
private String name,password;

    //getters and setters 
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

public void validate() {  
    if(name.length()<1)  
        addFieldError("name","Name can't be blank");  
    if(password.length()<6)  
        addFieldError("password","Password must be greater than 5");  
}  

public String execute(){  
//perform business logic here  
    return "success";  
}  
}
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction">  
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>  
    </package>
</struts>
```

Please check the code and let me know where i am making mistake in this validation example.

Error on tomcat console:

```
No result defined for action com.org.my.action.RegisterAction and result input
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Jan 09, 2014 12:20:41 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.jdk.JdkLogger error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: No result defined for action com.org.my.action.RegisterAction and result input
No result defined for action com.org.my.action.RegisterAction and result input
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

thanks for all who can help me...

Comment: Please Somebody Help Me...

Comment: Did you restart your web server?

Comment: i have restart my server as i am using netbeans7.4 IDE. but still i am getting same error.

Comment: I am still waiting please somebody help me. is there anybody who know the problem ?

Comment: Post the contents of `WEB-INF/lib` of your deployment artifact.

Comment: Content of WEB-INF/lib:
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - struts2-convention-plugin2.3.15.3.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 -  ognl-3.0.6.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - freemarker-2.3.19.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - commons-lang3-3.1.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - commons-io-2.0.1.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - asm-tree-3.3.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - asm-commons-3.3.jar
Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - asm-3.3.jar

Comment: @Bob.Z why did you ask to restart the web server? In my case the issue happens frequently and restarting the web server solves the issue!! I am unable to figure out why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem i resolved this error:

You need to do one change in your index.jsp file. Change the action in form.
(try both form lines one by one)

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
    <s:form action="RegisterAction.action">  or  <s:form action="register.action"> 
        <s:textfield name="name" label="Name"></s:textfield>  
        <s:password name="password" label="Password"></s:password>  
        <s:submit value="register"></s:submit>  
    </s:form>
```

I hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport{  
    private String name,password;
```

Separate into

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport{  
    private String name;
    private String password;
```

Comment: I have also changed the sequence of result as describe above but still same problem.

Comment: and also declare variable as private String name; in next line private String password; but still same problem.

Comment: Content of WEB-INF/lib: Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - struts2-convention-plugin2.3.15.3.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - ognl-3.0.6.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - freemarker-2.3.19.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - commons-lang3-3.1.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - commons-io-2.0.1.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - commons-fileupload-1.3.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - asm-tree-3.3.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - asm-commons-3.3.jar Struts2 Core 2.3.15 - asm-3.3.jar

Comment: I have resolved my problem own by just change action name from register to regi and same in index.jsp file action name from register to regi. i think name of button and action name are same due to that this problem appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work .
Change your `struts.xml` code

```
<struts>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction">  
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>  
</package>
```

to

```
<struts>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction">  
        <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
    </action>  
</package>
```

Just change the sequence of results .. First define `success` and then `input`

Comment: The order of the results is irrelevant.

Comment: I did not try that In my local system. But i have taken refence from [Struts2 validation documentation ](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/form-validation.html)..  Correct me if I am wrong check the paragraph `Handle Input Being Returned`

Comment: It is just a suggestion.

Comment: No Issue any other suggestion please let me know so that my demo will work.

Answer (score 0):

check your web.xml.
your web.xml has the below filters?

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <listener>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess you know how struts work and you have done everything correct but still fail to find out what's wrong with your project.
You have your action class name mentioned correctly and methods name are correct. Result pages are set correctly but still it fails. I have one thing that you should check. 
For example, if you are taking name and age from web page and in action class you have set name as string and age as int as member variable of same class or in model driven fashion. In web page for testing purpose you have enter characters in both name and age. In such case struts will check for action class which takes string as name and age but fails to find it. Because the action class you created takes name as string and age as int. Hence 404 error is thrown.

or you can try this.

I have found that changing the input helps in resolving this issue. I started my web application from the beginning by giving it proper refresh and it seem to resolve the issue.

[gyakhoe.com](http://www.gyakhoe.com)

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<struts>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction">  
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>  
</package>
</struts>
```

to

```
<struts>
<!-- Configuration for the default package. -->
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction">  
        <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
    </action>  
</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change this -

```
<action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction">
```

to

```
 <action name="register" class="com.org.my.action.RegisterAction" method="execute">
```

in your Struts.xml file

Thanks